# why animation not working when i put a slash in id of a li menu?

Tags: html

The below code works the animation that is when i click a menu like services, it will float to services div with an animation. But when i put `<li><a href="/#services">Services</a></li>`  like this ie "/#services", the animation doesn't work. why any idea?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
      <a href="#aboutus">About US</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/Home/Contact">Contact US</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" data-target="#login" data-toggle="modal">
        Sign in
      </a>
    </li>
    @*
    <li class="btn-trial">
      <a href="#footer">Free Trail</a>
    </li>
    *@
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `href="#services"` redirects you to the same page, but `href="/#services"` redirects you to the root directory. Take a look at your address bar when you click on the link in both situations to understand.

```
   /   = Root directory
   .   = This location
   ..  = Up a directory
   ./  = Current directory
   ../ = Parent of current directory
   ../../ = Two directories backwards
```